# Gauge meter in SVG with round corner

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I lately started working with SVG's and I am working on gauge meter. The design has round corner.

[image]

I have found one nice plugin to make a gauge widget. But it does not have any option to provide round corners. https://codepen.io/naikus/pen/BzkoLL

There was another nice blow I found on gauge widget. This is a different way but no way to round the circle corners.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="gauge">
  <path class="dial" fill="none" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="2" d="M 21.716 78.284 A 40 40 0 1 1 78.284 78.284"></path>
  <text x="50" y="50" fill="#999" class="value-text" font-size="100%" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle">36</text>
  <path class="value" fill="none" stroke="#666" stroke-width="2.5" d="M 21.716 78.284 A 40 40 0 0 1 24.796 18.94"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `stroke-linecap` attribute on your `paths` and give it the value `"round"` :

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="gauge">
  <path class="dial" fill="none" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="2" d="M 21.716 78.284 A 40 40 0 1 1 78.284 78.284" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
  <text x="50" y="50" fill="#999" class="value-text" font-size="100%" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle">36</text>
  <path class="value" fill="none" stroke="#666" stroke-width="2.5" d="M 21.716 78.284 A 40 40 0 0 1 24.796 18.94" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
</svg>
```